# Waveform result of an equation

Tags: digital-logic, waveform

[image]

I have this waveform and I would like to have the Y.

I know that the equation is `Y = D' + E' + F'`.

Where it has `'` it means [NOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation).

As I see it, the only thing I did, and I am not sure if it is right, was this:

[image]

If I got it right, this is it:

[image]

Comment: At the very beginning, D' is True, so Y should also be True.

Comment: you mean I am right @ErikR ?

Comment: You've drawn Y as being False at the beginning and only True near the end (where the bump is)

Comment: yes  because I think it is the whole "result" from all D',E',F'. I show from those where they have same "bump"

Comment: At the beginning, D, E and F are all False. So D', E' and F' are all True, so Y = D'+E'+F' is True.

Comment: I think I understand . You are telling me that if I have D,E,F the Y i DRAW it will be ok. BUT now because it is D',E',F' it is wrong?

Comment: If Y = D+E+F, then the first part of Y (up to the first vertical line) would look like F. Note that A+B means A OR B.

Comment: yes I know and A AND B are A * B.  I am not sure what you mean by that on waveform.This part I did not get it "If Y = D+E+F, then the first part of Y (up to the first vertical line) would look like F"

Comment: Hint: What's the **DeMorgan equivalent** of D'+E'+F'? It's (DEF)'. In C notation !(D&E&F).

Comment: and what that has to do with the waveform?

Comment: Your waveform is inverted.

Comment: wow you mean I must do it upside down?

Comment: @hacktastical I editted .Do you mean that? this is the solution?that you mean?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Yun.kon - your last graph is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the analysis graphically.

Any red section in `D`, `E` or `F` will cause `Y` to be true.

You will also see that `D` is not required to generate `Y`.

[image]

Comment: D is not required to generate Y WITH this example.

Answer (score 4):

The exercise shows the application of **DeMorgan's Theorem**. Stated simply,

- **A'+ B'** is equivalent to **(AB)'** (negative-in OR into positive-in NAND)

Likewise,

- **A'B'** is equivalent to **(A+B)'** (negative-in AND into positive-in NOR)

In this case, you have three inputs. Doesn't matter, DeMorgan's Theorem extends to any number of inputs:

- Y = D'+E'+F'

converts to..

- Y = (DEF)'

that is, the NAND of the three inputs.

Y will be **low** when all three inputs are **high**. Based on the sequence, Y will pulse low **only at the end, when DEF are all high.**

More about DeMorgan's Theorem here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/demorgan.html

Do a truth table for both (D' + E' + F') and (DEF)'. They will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are already good, but since you have all inputs negated, then it might help you to simply flip the picture up-side down:

[image: flip]

All that's left is to see where all of the three traces are `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Y is equal to the sum of (not D), (not E) and (not F), it will be true whenever any one of D, E and F is not true. For then at least one of the three terms will be true. Thus, in your diagram, Y will be true or high whenever any of D, E and F is not true or low. It will only be not true or low whenever all of D, E and F are true or high. You should be able to construct Y from this information.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to read the boolean equation `Y=D'+E'+F'` is `D is false OR E is false OR F is false`.

If you understand how to translate from your boolean to my English equivalent, the correct answer should be obvious. If any of D, E, or F are false, the output will be true. So it's always high, except when all three inputs are true.

Answer (score -2):

Times 1, 2 and 3 are indicated by the green lines.

At time 1, D, E and F are all False.

At time 2, D and E are False and F is True.

At time 3, D is False, E is True and F is False.

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect.

Comment: why it is incorrect

Comment: Missed the inversion for (D'+E'+F') = (DEF)'.

Comment: @hacktasical - Y is from the OP's answer. I was just explaining how the logic levels are determined for D, E, and F.

Comment: You still don't show the correct logic or waveform.

Comment: I'm not going to do the entire exercise for the OP. It's clear the OP was having trouble understanding how to read the traces.